# How to retrieve browser web console log and write it into a file?

Tags: javascript, automation, casperjs

I am trying to process the log from a specific webpage. Are there any suggestions how to retrieve the logs and put into text file from any web page using CasperJS?

Comment: If they're logging to the _Console_ then you could _shadow_ `console.log`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) event to receive all `console.log()` from the page. Using that, you can write them into a file using PhantomJS' fs module ([`fs.write()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html)).

```
var fs = require('fs');
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    fs.write("file", msg+"\n", "a");
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Keep a reference to the original function
var original = console.log;

//Override the function
console.log = function(arg) {

   //Do what you want with the arguments of the function
   ....

  //Call the original function
  original.call(this, arguments);
}
```